# Javascript async and polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to make an element for the new jsfiddle embedding, it requires me to change the username and fiddle id on the fly (so I made some properties).

But the script searches for //jsfiddle.net///embed/ I'm guess this means the script tag is being triggered before it the properties are bound. Here is my code.

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module name="jsfiddle-demo">
  <template>
    <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/{{username}}/{{fiddle}}/embed/"></script>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'jsfiddle-demo',
      properties: {
        username: {
          type: String,
          value: ''
        },
        fiddle: {
          type: String,
          value: ''
        },
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
<jsfiddle-demo username="link2twenty" fiddle="6ppzpuoq"></jsfiddle-demo>
```

and a like to an active [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/6ppzpuoq/)

Comment: I removed the default value for the strings and made it so that the url is in a computed binding in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/77dv87ne/1/) (so that the script src attribute is only set if both username and fiddle are defined) but it seems there's some other problem left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username and fiddle properties are in fact empty at the point in time when the script tag is added to the DOM. Even after updating them the script is not reloaded.

Wrap the script tag in an if-template in order to let polymer add it to the DOM only if username and fiddle are both present.

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module name="jsfiddle-demo">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-if" restamp if="[[usernameAndFiddlePresent(username, fiddle)]]">
      <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/{{username}}/{{fiddle}}/embed/"></script>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'jsfiddle-demo',
      properties: {
        username: {
          type: String,
          value: ''
        },
        fiddle: {
          type: String,
          value: ''
        },
      },
      usernameAndFiddlePresent: function(username, fiddle) {
        return (username && fiddle); 
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
<jsfiddle-demo username="link2twenty" fiddle="6ppzpuoq"></jsfiddle-demo>
```

The `restamp` attribute is the key. It tells polymer to actually remove or add the elements inside the template to the DOM, instead of just showing/hiding them.
The expression is evaluated every time either username of fiddle properties change.

Theoretically, if you'd like to change the username or fiddle on the fly, you could just unset one of the properties and then reset it to something else. This should give you a new script tag with a different src.

Comment: There is now a new error, but you solved the error in question. Thanks :-)